# accessing subtype method from supertype arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism

I am learning polymorphism and having some issues. I'm essentially supposed to make a "screensaver" with different images moving and bouncing around. I got that working using an array of the four subtypes Square, Star, Circle and Triangle, however I can only have one instance of a single class at a time (when I click, it makes a new shape and the old one disappears).

I've attempted making an arraylist like this:

```
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        if (i < 3) {
            i += 1;
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            shapeArray.add(new Circle());
            break;
        case 1:
            shapeArray.add( new Square());
            break;
        case 2:
            shapeArray.add( new Star());
            break;
        case 3:
            shapeArray.add(new Triangle());
            break;

        }
        shapeArray.get(i).setX(e.getX());
        shapeArray.get(i).setY(e.getY());

        repaint();
        animationTimer.start();
        j += 1;
}
```

but when I call my draw method in paintComponent-

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        shapeArray.get(i).draw(g, this);
//      shapeArray.get(i).bounce(g, this);

    }// end paintComponent
```

-I get errors from the call of the draw method. Am I on the right track? how do I call this method of the subtype using a superclass arraylist?

EDIT: 
abstract superclass:

```
public abstract class Shapes {
    Graphics g;
    protected int width = 0;
    protected int height = 0;
    protected int x = 0;
    protected int y = 0;
    int d = 5;
    int c = 5;
    Random myRandom = new Random();


    protected Color colorArray[] = {new Color(255,0,0),new Color(255,179,0),new Color(255,255,0),
            new Color(7,225,0),new Color(0,127,225),new Color(205,0,255)};
    protected Color color;

    public Integer RandomNum(Integer x){
        myRandom = new Random();
        return myRandom.nextInt(x);
    }
abstract public void draw(Graphics g, JPanel jp);

abstract public void bounce(Graphics g,JPanel jp);
public void setWidth(Integer width) {
    this.width = width;
}
```

subclass constructor and draw method:

```
public Circle() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = RandomNum(100);
    this.height = width;
    this.color = colorArray[RandomNum(6)];
}

public void draw(Graphics g, JPanel jp) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    int radius = width;
    Point2D center = new Point2D.Float((x + width / 2), (y + height / 2));
    Point2D focus = new Point2D.Float(x - (radius * 0.6f), y
            - (radius * 0.6f));
    float[] dist = { 0.1f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
    Color[] colors = { Color.WHITE,
            color, color };
    RadialGradientPaint p = new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, focus,
            dist, colors, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE);
    if (g2d != null) {
        g2d.setPaint(p);
        int r2 = radius / 2;
        g2d.fillOval(x - r2, y - r2, radius, radius);
    }

    // g.setColor(colorArray[RandomNum(colorArray.length)]);
    // g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);

}
```

Comment: Either cast or define the method in the superclass. Here (and most places) you want to define it in the superclass. For polymorphism, youd then override it in the subclass.

Comment: I have an abstract method in the superclass, which is overridden in each subclass. Is there anything I need to change to access the overrides using the arraylist?

Comment: There shouldnt be. As long as the other classes arent abstract or anything. Could you post a short snippet of the presumably Shape class with its abstract bounce() and the other classes with their bounce()?

Comment: And the draw() too. Thats where the error happened you said.

Comment: Done. All this was working when I was using a regular object array, but now that I need to have more than one shape at a time I assume that an arraylist is the way to do it. But I can't get it to work.

Comment: Well you can do it with a `Shape[]` array. In this case, im not sure what the problem is. Idk anything about java graphics. What specifically is the error you get?

Comment: The trouble with arrays is the fixed size thing

Comment: yeah, exactly. because of the fixed size thing seems to be why I can only have one instance of an object at a time because it was just going through that one array over and over. with an array list I can create a new instance of an object whenever I want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're only ever having one shape at a time, you don't need an ArrayList to begin with; just have a variable of type Shapes (or whatever your superclass is called) that you assign a new Circle or new Square or whatever to inside that switch of yours.

With the ArrayList, though, I see two things that may be problems: first, you may be just using a basic ArrayList instead of an ArrayList of your type (ie `private ArrayList shapesArray` instead of `private ArrayList<Shapes> shapesArray`); second, your Shapes class doesn't have an abstract setX/setY method, so you'll get errors after your switch in mouseClicked.

Comment: I need to have more than one shape at a time, that's why I'm asking the question. I have the type of arraylist on there ( private ArrayList<Shapes> shapeArray = new ArrayList<>();
) and there is a setter and getter for x and y I just didn't put them in the post to save room. oddly I'm not having any trouble with the setter and getter, just with the draw method.

Comment: What error are you getting, exactly? Could you perhaps put all your code in a pastebin and link it?